# How to get the angle between the camera and the object using python,realsense SDK

Tags: intel, realsense

I'm working on a project on python and I'm using D415 Intel Realsense camera.
On Realsense SDK you can find the measurement of the angle between the camera and the object, is it possible to get this angle measurement from the SDK by python? 
in the photo, I add more explanation.

[demo of the camera and the object from the SDK](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B06kf.jpg)

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Hi Mbuechamann,
Well,  i'm still reading the documentation of the realsense but i haven't found anything to try it.
Finding the angle is a small part of my project and i don't think i need to calculate it by my self as long as it's on the SDK i think it has to be something like when we ask for the depth (frame.get_distance(x,y))
it has to be something like 3D_frame.get_angle(rectangle((X, Y), (X1, Y1)